# Is $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2-x^3)$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

First, I'd like to show $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2-x^3)$ is an integral domain.  Then I need to find out whether or not it is a PID.

For the first part, I want to show $y^2-x^3 \: | \: fg \implies y^2-x^3 \: | \: f$ or $y^2-x^3 \: | \: g$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.  I could not get past this.

For the second part, I was thinking of maybe showing $(y^2-x^3)$ is maximal; then the quotient would be a field and hence a PID.  Again, I couldn't get further than this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: see that $(y^2-x^3)$ is not a maximal ideal as $(y^2-x^3)\subsetneq (x,y)$

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/622095/39281

Comment: Hint for the second part: is it even a UFD?

Comment: You mean PID, right? Look at the maximal ideal $(x,y)$. Is it principal?

Comment: @Dune: Are you talking to me? I'm saying the ring isn't even a UFD, so it can't be a PID.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Of course you are right. Actually, in this case being UFD or PID is equivalent since all non-zero prime ideals are maximal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zero set of $Y^2-X^3$ is a one-dimensional curve with a [cusp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_%28singularity%29) at $(0,0)$. From the picture it is clear that the tangent spaces at roots $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$ are one-dimensional while the tangent space at $(0,0)$ is two-dimensional. Translating these geometric properties into algebraic properties, it means that $\dim_\mathbb{C}(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2) = 1$ for $\mathfrak{m} = (X-a,Y-b)$ with $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$ and $\dim_\mathbb{C}(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2) = 2$ for $\mathfrak{m} = (X,Y)$, where these ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ are considered to be ideals of the coordinate ring $R = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$. This in turn is equivalent to saying that all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$ but $(X,Y)$ are principal in $R_\mathfrak{m}$, and $(X,Y)$ is not. In particular, $(X,Y)$ cannot be principal in $R$.

Of course we cannot argue by looking at the picture here, so it is your turn to give an algebraic proof that $\mathfrak{m} = (X,Y)$ is not principal, or equivalently, that $\dim_\mathbb{C}(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2) \geq 2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ has no principal maximal ideals.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! I've corrected my claim.

Answer (score 5):

Any PID is a UFD, and any UFD is integrally closed. But $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is not integrally closed, since $t:=y/x$ satisfies $t^2=x$ and $t^3=y$.

Comment: How would you argue that $t$ is not contained in $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$?

Comment: $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is a free $k[x]$-module with basis $1,y$, hence a free $k$-module with basis $x^{\mathbb{N}} \cup x^{\mathbb{N}} y$. This basis is invariant under multiplication with $x$. Then it is clear that there is no element $t$ with $tx=y$.

Comment: Alternatively, consider $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3) \to k[t]$, $x \mapsto t^2$, $y \mapsto t^3$ and observe that $t$ is clearly not contained in the image (for example by degree considerations).

Comment: Great, thanks! By the way, the second argument also immediately shows that $(x,y)$ is not principal.