# Prove that A is isomorphic to the subring of K[T] generated by $T^2$ and $T^3$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A = K[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^3\rangle$. Show that $A$ is isomorphic to the subring of $K[T]$ generated by $T^2$, $T^3$.

I tried to show a map from $\phi : A \to K[T]$ which sends $x \to T^2$ and $y \to T^3$ is an isomorphism. But couldn't prove it.  Can anyone help me out?

Also,

> Show that fraction field of $A \cong K(T)=$ (field of rational functions in $T$) .

Comment: The linked question doesn't ask the same thing as this one, but [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/622179/121097) solves the present question, too.

Comment: The last question (added later) is trivial: $T=T^3/T^2$.