# How to prove $ x^2 + y^3$ irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am given a remark that "every irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is exactly of degree 1",

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622095/verifying-that-the-ideal-x3-y2-is-prime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is irreducible in $(\mathbb C(y))[x]$, since it is a quadric without a root over a field.

As a polynomial in $(\mathbb C[y])[x]$ it is primitive (even monic), thus it is irreducible in that ring by Gauß' Lemma.

Comment: Can u explain your answer in more detail?

Comment: @Toya The first line is all you need.

Comment: Does it make sense if I choose a root of $ iy^{3/2} $?

Comment: How is that contained in $\mathbb C(y)$?

Comment: Get it, thanks Bro