# Computing the kernel of a morphism whose domain and codomain are polynomial algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ denote a field.

If $\varphi$ is a $k$-linear map between $k$-modules freely generated by finite sets, then the kernel of $\varphi$ can easily be found by reinterpreting $\varphi$ as a matrix and performing row-reduction.

Suppose instead that $\varphi$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism between $k$-algebras freely generated by finite sets, i.e. between polynomial algebras in finitely-many indeterminates. Is there a way of explicitly computing the kernel of such a map?

Let's look at a really simple example. Suppose we want to show that $$\frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{(y-x^2)} \cong \mathbb{R}[x],$$

for example. A reasonable place to start is to define $\varphi$ to be the unique morphism of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras $$\mathbb{R}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$$ satisfying $\varphi(x)=x$ and $\varphi(y) = x^2$. This is clearly surjective, and presumably the kernel of this map is $(y-x^2),$ thereby giving the desired result via the first isomorphism theorem.

Part of my question is: if $\varphi$ were more complicated, how could we work out what it's kernel was? Is there a systematic approach, like there is in linear algebra?

Part of my question is also about rigor. In the particular example of $\varphi$ given above, since $\varphi(x) = x$, thus $\varphi(x^2) = x^2$, so $\varphi(y - x^2) = 0$. Thus $(y-x^2) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(\varphi)$. I'm a bit unsure how to go the other way. Supposing $\varphi(P) = 0$, how can we show that $P \in (y - x^2)$? And is there a method that works generally, even for much more complicate examples?

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622095/verifying-that-the-ideal-x3-y2-is-prime).

Comment: In your example, the image is an integral domain, so the kernel is a prime ideal. The height of $(y-x^2)$ is already $1$, so any prime containing it would be maximal. I can't give any general advice for calculating kernels; when forced to do so I generally resort to ad hoc methods.